# How to speed up opencv bitwise_or when operating over a Mat array for video processing application?

Tags: opencv, video, processing, bitwise-or

The following function is running too slow for video processing. Any suggestions on how to speed it up?
I have tried using opencv parallel_for_ but only to find that it will run even slower.

Any advises?

```
void f13(Mat srcimage, Mat* masks, Mat& out){
out = masks[0];
for(int i=1;i<49;i++) {
out |= srcimage|masks[i];
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to perform an OR with `srcimage` each time. Set `out = srcimage;` and then `out |= masks[i];` for all of the masks.

Comment: Also, if your `srcimage` changes, but your masks remain the same, you can OR together all of your masks ahead of time and just return `srcimage | allmasks`.